# swift declare a constant without let

Tags: swift

In `Swift programming language` we can declare a constant like that :

```
 let sth = "something"
```

but I found that we can write

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
```

it doesn't use the keyword let, so what does that mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That means that you're modifying an existing instance property of a class. I'd guess you did this inside your app delegate or a `UIView` subclass.

Normally you must use either `let` or `var`, so if you're able to assign a value to `window` without one of those keywords it's because the scope you're in already has it declared.

Comment: thanks, I think this is the most suitable explanation

Answer (score 1):

```
 window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
```

If you are trying to write this code then you must have declare a variable like this :

```
var window: UIWindow?
```

The **let** keyword is used to define constant. And Its value can not be change afterwords. **Var** is used to define variables.

You can give a try your above line of code without declaring a Variable. It will give you an error for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Any declaration, whether it is a constant or a variable has to be made using the `let` (for constant) and `var` (for variable) keywords. For example

```
var window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
let window2 = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
```

`window` is a variable because it is created using `var` and `window2` is a constant because it is created using `let`. Now in the code below

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
window2 = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)//error
```

line 1 will work properly but line 2 will give an error because you cannot re-assign a value to a constant.

You can try the above code in a playground and check the error.